# Which is the best way to run a cron job every 30 seconds?

Tags: bash, cron, cron-task

I would like to run a cron job every 30 seconds, but cron does not allow scheduling jobs more frequently than once a minute.

Which is the best way to run a cron job every 30 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do this while avoiding the sliding window issue.  Create two scripts, your main one (main.sh here) and a sleep script (sleep30.sh):

main.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
date >>/tmp/main.out
```

sleep30.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 30
. $1
```

crontab:

```
* * * * * /pathtoscripts/sleep30.sh /pathtoscripts/main.sh
* * * * * /pathtoscripts/main.sh
```

It's inelegant, but should work.

Answer (score 2):

In case task execution time is short and can be neglected, you can do it this way:

```
* * * * * /path/cmd; sleep 30; /path/cmd
```

Answer (score 1):

The shortest time interval you can use with cron is 1 minute.
You could put a sleep in a bash script, but that would probably be the best you can do

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that you can't schedule cron jobs under a minute. You can use `sleep 30` but that introduces sliding window problems (the task is now intervaled at 30 seconds + run time of the task). You can put the task inside a `while true` loop and have it check each iteration if at least 30 seconds have passed, and if so - run the task again, and if not `sleep 1`

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to the latest beta of FreeBSD which has a special new cron modifier: @every_second.
Wrap your cronjob in lockf, sleep for 30 seconds, run the job, and terminate. This way you can run it twice a minute.